# Displaying google analytics data on my website

Tags: analytics

I sell ad space for my websites directly to the advertisers. I ad page where I want to show Google Analytics information that updates automatically without me having to manually update everyday or every month.

Something like this: http://wstats.net/en/website/riverplate.com#stat_trafic

I don't want to use embedded or iframed third party services.

I know Google has a public API and you can connect it to Google Graph API to to show pretty graphs. There is a tutorial by Google here on how to do it: https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gdataAnalyticsCharts

Few problems:

- I don't know much javascript
- The javascript seems to prompt for authentication as opposed to login automatically, from my understanding by reading comments on the code.

Does anyone know of any ready made script that does what I am looking for or know how I can fix this code that will allow me to display analytics info without authenticating?

Answer (score 1):

Try using http://www.seethestats.com/ it's pretty simple since you're not good with Javascript.

Comment: Isn't there any other solution to this? There must be some out there...

Comment: If you do not know PHP or jQuery/Javascript to use the Google Analytics API. I would hire a programmer to integrate using http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/ which is simple and quick. Then display your basic stats in text and style them with CSS. Run a cron script to update daily, weekly, or monthly.